# Who is Dhul-Qarnayn?

Tags: tafseer, prophets

I understand there are different opinions about who Dhu al-Qarnayn is, and what the name really means:

> وَيَسْأَلُونَكَ عَن ذِي الْقَرْنَيْنِ ۖ قُلْ سَأَتْلُو عَلَيْكُم مِّنْهُ ذِكْرًا
>
> And they ask you, [O Muhammad], about Dhul-Qarnayn. Say, "I will recite to you about him a report."
>
> [Surat Al-Kahf, Verse 83](https://quran.com/18/83)

### Who is Dhul-Qarnayn?

Points to think about when answering:

- The people who asked about Dhul-Qarnayn and their relationship to him
  (I. e yasalonaka..)
- The description given about the events in 18:83 - 18:98 *(i.e power, bulding barrier, travel from east to west and so on)*
- If he was a king, Prophet or a ruler.
- If he was a "muslim" (or believer).

Whatever sources are needed to answer the question "who is dhul-qarnayn" is accepted, Islamic sources are of course preferable while identifying him with a historical person mentioned by Israelite legends or other legends are of course okay. All sources and theories should be well referenced and should met the points mentioned above. If you want to add counter arguments why Dhul-Qarynayn cannot be X, that would be a bonus. Analytical and structured answers are always preferable.

Comment: Oh, it seems to be an informative query, I honestly don't know what is the reason for voting to close that?!

Comment: @اللهمصلعلیمحمدوآلمحمد Thanks, and yeah, I am not sure what is so unclear with my question... Could the ones who want to close this explain what is unclear?

Comment: Yes, precisely. BTW, honestly, it was my question/doubt too to have more information about who exactly he is (as a constructive/helpful question). Good luck.

Comment: Of course, I found the following links which seem to be helpful about that, namely: http://en.wikishia.net/view/Dhu_l-Qarnayn

Comment: @اللهمصلعلیمحمدوآلمحمد Yes that is a good link, I think the link about Razi I added has some good information (mentioned in the link you posted too), so if someone want to answer accordingly that would be good. But then my wish is also that when they answer and explain who dhul-qarnayn is, that they think about the points i mentioned in my question. Because for instance, some scholars would disagree about him being Alexander the Great, because he is said to not been monotheist, (which Razi seems to argue against, saying he was the pupil of Aristotles).

Comment: Yes, factually there can be a persuasive/informative answer(s) by using those two links. Unfortunately, I'm busy (at least currently), otherwise I like to provide/research an appropriate response for that interesting question, especially for such queries which seem to be ... Jazak Allah Khaira.

Comment: You should probably explain what exactly you require from an answer within the body of the question. Do you want a description of him in Islamic sources or are you seeking an identification to a historical person or Israeilite legend? Regarding identification, as you've stated yourself there are numerous opinions from him being an Angel to being Alexander to someone like Melchizedek. Do you want a listing of these opinions? Do you want an analysis of them? Do you want people to give their own takes and theories? If you want all of this then the question might be too broad?

Comment: @Uma Honestly I don't see why this would be closed as unclear what you are asking. Of course adding more explanation would be good, and I've done that now, hope its more clear. Atm there are many similar questions, (see the related questions) eg: "Who is Elisha?" , it seems these questions didn't get closed. Anyway the reason I asked this question wasn't because I am unfamiliar with the different theories, rather I wanted to add this question to our community, since many questions ask stuff related to this. It will be easier to answer (or close) them then.

Comment: It might also help drive the quality of the questions up, so many of them still seem to be, to be honest, kinda weird for want of a better word.

Comment: @Kilise See, if the asker for 'Who is Elisha?' gave the link of the wikipedia page and the tafsirs in the question then it would be hard to figure out what more they want. If you know the answer and your intention is to make this a *reference question* then I think you should mention that and should answer it as well, mentioning and explaining the tafsirs in an answer.